# Validate that scope is present

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, claims-based-identity

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC Project. Authentication is performed using an oidc identity provider.
The client requests a scope "myscope". This scope is added to the access token.

```
  .AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    ...
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

    // options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("scope", "scope");
    
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("myscope");
    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = (x) => {
      var props = x.Properties;
      // here i can inspect the access token and see the scope is present
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
  });
```

As well i can retrieve the access token from the HttpContext to eventually pass it to an api. But at the moment i want to access my database directly.
Thus i thought i want to validate that the scope "myscope" is present. I want to achieve that using a policy.

```
    services.AddMvc(options => {
      var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
         .RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "myscope")
         .Build();
      options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
```

The authorization unfortunately fails. The reason is, that the claims from the access token are not mapped into the User Claims Principal. MapJsonKey does not help here as well.
How can i check if a scope (of the access token) is present using authorization policies?

I am as well thinking about, if i am trying a pointless approach. I am using Identity Server 4 as my identity provider. The scope is specified as an api resource. Maybe you could argue that the scope should be an identity resource, thus being present in the id token and therefore mapped to the ClaimsPrincipal.

Comment: have you tried manually verifying the claims by debugging? it's what we should do when the claims-based authorization is not working. Almost the cases of bug mean the required claims are not present in the request. Then that will be the question asked.

Comment: Yes when debugging i can grab the access token and decode it using jwt.io and i see that the scope is present (await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")). When i check the Identity of the User property in the controller, the scope claim type is not present.

Comment: Have you verified that the token contains the data you expect? Copy the Base64 encoded version of it from the authorization header and paste it into jwt.ms. That will decode it for you.

Comment: @DiegoFrehner, did you ever get anywhere with this? I have the same problem. I've asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69654675/181771

Answer (score 0):

by default you need to be explicit and tell which claims you want from the tokens and user-info endpoint to end up in the user object (Claims principal), by adding this to the AddOpenIDConnect options

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("website", "website");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("myscope", "myscope");
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("birthdate", "birthdate");
```

You should also add a IdentityResource definition, because it controls what goes into the ID-Token , like

```
        _identityResources = new List<IdentityResource>()
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Email(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResources.Address(),
            "myscope"
        };
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mentioned as well that as an identity resource it would work because id token claims are mapped to the ClaimsPrincipal, in contrast to access token claims.I am using an ApiResource and an ApiScope. To me it appears that access to a specific api or application data should be an access token claim and not an identity resource. But maybe there my understanding is wrong. Because if my client app would pass the access token to an api to retrieve data and not access the database directly i would require the claims in the access token as well.

Comment: You use ApiScope and ApiResources to map the claims in the access token. and the IdentityResource for the ID-token.

Comment: Yes. Are you suggesting that i should always specify both ApiResource and IdentityResource? To my understanding of (https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html) identity resources should express properties of the identity like email or name. And ApiResources models resources of your application, as for example accessing a specific api/data.

Comment: To be more specific about "myscope". It should express "has access to call center data". That's information i would want to have in the access token not in the identity token. It would be convenient if the web front end can limit access to certain pages using the Authorizatin Policies. But it seems that using authorization policies does not allow to check claims of the access token, but only claims of the identity token. Therefore my question. "How can i check if a scope (of the access token) is present using authorization policies?"

Comment: OpenIDConnect /tokens is all about authentication, who is the user. You use the authorization to then check if the user is allowed.   What you can limit on is the audience claim in the access token.  The scope is only about what the client asked to get access to and then you need to do the final check in the authorization part to really check if the user is allowed.

Comment: it is also the question who you wan to check for the myscope claim. in the MVC client,  you need it to be in the ID-token, because that is part of the user. The client never looks inside the access token.   If you want to do the check in the API, then you need to put it in the access token.

Comment: does this make the answer acceptable? :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229251/discussion-between-diego-frehner-and-tore-nestenius).